# Selecting top n rows from a category(column) in a pandas dataframe and perform calculations on it

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to pandas, I'm analyzing FIFA dataset, I need to select the top 5 players(based on Overall score), for each positions.

Also,

I want to check, if there are any players, who is present in more than one group, for the above condition.
2. To perform operations such as mean, max on individual groups.

Thanks

I couldn't retrieve other columns like Name and Wage, when I use this operation.

`fifa_df.groupby('Position')['Overall'].nlargest(5).groupby('Position').head()`

Sample Data:
[image]
Expecting results like below:

[image]

also I'm trying to find, all the players present in more than one group,

and trying to do operations like average wage for the top 5 players in each position.

dataset link - [fifa_dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/karangadiya/fifa19/downloads/fifa19.zip/4)

Comment: kindly add sample data and code not pictures

Comment: hi Tawab, i've added the link to the dataset

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try using nlargest in apply

```
res = df[['Name','Position','Overall','Wage']]
res= res.groupby(['Position'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(5, 'Overall'))
res.reset_index(inplace=True)
data.drop(['level_0','level_1'],axis=1,inplace=True)
print(data)
```

```
    Name       Position Overall Wage
0   A. Griezmann    CAM 89     €145K
1   C. Eriksen      CAM 88     €205K
2   Roberto Firmino CAM 86     €195K
3   T. Müller       CAM 86     €135K
4   M. Özil         CAM 86     €190K
5   D. Godín        CB  90     €125K
6   S. Umtiti       CB  87     €205K
7   M. Benatia      CB  86     €160K
8   N. Otamendi     CB  85     €170K
9   Naldo           CB  85     €38K
....
```

I hope it would solve your problem

Comment: no problem @GokulElumalai,upvote if you found it helpfull

Comment: sure tawab. just one question, do i have to create seperate dataframes, if i want to check whether there are any common players between two group(based on positions)?

Comment: you can do 
`res= df.groupby(['Position'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(5, 'Overall'))`

Answer (score 4):

```
fifa_df.sort_values('Overall', ascending=False).groupby('Position').head(5).sort_values(['Position', 'Overall'], ascending=False)
```

---

```
    Name                Position    Overall Wage
1   Cristiano Ronaldo   ST          94      €405K
10  R. Lewandowski      ST          90      €205K
23  S. Agüero           ST          89      €300K
16  H. Kane             ST          89      €205K
36  G. Bale             ST          88      €355K
517 S. Coleman          RWB         80      €97K
465 P. Kadeřábek        RWB         80      €39K
450 M. Ginter           RWB         80      €28K
652 D. Caligiuri        RWB         79      €33K
766 Pablo Maffeo        RWB         78      €24K
...
```

Comment: your answer is easy for me remember, thanks for answering @political_scientist

Comment: @GokulElumalai glad I could help! I tried to find the simplest solution